# Record native mobile app with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to record mobile app with Jmeter, the app has URLs with https,
I am using jmeter 3.1 and configured mobile and machine such that I am able to record URL(both http and HTTPS) and app from mobile in jmeter. Now I have an application, with the same configuration I have tried recording that app, but not able to record anything and the strange thing is that when I am trying to login into the app with proxy in mobile it's says "Unable to connect to server", but without proxy it's logining successfully. Does someone come across this situation. Please let me know if there could be any solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

`Unable to connect to server` has many faces, going forward include more details into the question, i.e. mobile operating system, proxy configuration details, etc.

In the meantime here is a checklist:

- JMeter can record only HTTP and/or HTTPS, other protocols are not supported
- You need to configure mobile device to use the host running JMeter as a proxy for **both** HTTP and HTTPS protocols. For certain operating systems you may need 3rd party software, i.e [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en_GB) in order to setup HTTPS proxy
- In case of HTTPS traffic you will need to install JMete's self-signed certificate - `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` onto your mobile device. If did it already - be informed that JMeter certificates has limited life span (4 months or something like that) so you need to periodically "refresh" them. The fastest and the easiest way of installing the certificate is sending the aforementioned file to yourself via email and opening the attachment using the mobile device.

See **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) JMeter User Manual entry for more details.

You can also [View the Webcast: Performance Testing for Native Mobile Apps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/view-webcast-performance-testing-native-mobile-apps) to learn about alternative ways of recording mobile traffic and converting it into a JMeter test.

Comment: Below are the steps which I am following:

1.Connect (using Android 6.0) Mobile and Laptop on the same and open network.
2.Update Laptop IP and Port no. in Mobile device.
3.Start recording in Apache JMeter 3.0 using same port no. as set in mobile.

4. Installed jmeter CA certificate in mobile.

5.Perform the step in the app.

But there is error message in the mobile device which say unable to connect to device.

I have verified ip address and port no. on the device.

I also tried using Blazemeter option- facing same issue with that too.